# Returning child object from parent class type method

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

I am trying to write a method that creates random plants and returns the object of created plant as `Plant`. In example below the method `createPlant()` is of type `Plant` and returns an object of child class `Tree`. As it turns out my way of thinking is erroneous. The error provided by Eclipse is: "This method must return a result of type Plant". So how should I go about creating such method?

```
public abstract class Plant {
    ...
}

public class Tree extends Plant {
    ...
}

public class Bush extends Plant {
    ...
}

public class Map {
    private Plant plant;
    ...
    public static Plant createPlant(float x, float y) { // This method must return a result of type Plant
        Random generator = new Random();            
        switch (generator.nextInt(2)) {
            case 0:
                return new Tree(x, y);
            case 1:
                return new Bush(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a complete example reproducing the problem. What you posted looks fine to me.

Comment: `Tree` is a `Plant`. Isn't it.

Comment: Thanks to JB Nizet for pointing to the right direction, sorry for not providing the full problem the first time. The problem was in not defining the default case. What should I do with the question, should I leave it as it is, or is it better to remove it?

Comment: Im confused on what youre trying to do. Tree is of type Plant, so you are returning a Plant type; if you wanna return `new Plant`, you must extend on the instance by creating an anonymous class

Comment: Delete it, or answer it yourself after editing the question and posting the code which actually had the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add default case of `null`.

```
    switch (generator.nextInt(2)) {
        case 0:
            return new Tree(x, y);
        case 1:
            return new Bush(x, y);
        default:                         // Requires default case
            return null;
    }
```

Or create a dummy `NoPlant` class

```
  public class NoPlant extends Plant {
     ...
  }
```

Now use in this way

```
    switch (generator.nextInt(2)) {
        case 0:
            return new Tree(x, y);
        case 1:
            return new Bush(x, y);
        default:                         // Requires default case
            return new NoPlant();
    }
```

---

--EDIT--

Try in this way also

```
    int random=generator.nextInt(2); // return either 0 or 1

    if(random==0){
        return new Tree(x,y);
    }else{
        return new Bush(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. The OP's code is fine, and this NoPlant idea is a bad idea.

Comment: @JBNizet actually OP is looking for some default value that is not defined.

Comment: @Nigenas thanks for edit but remember `null` is not of type `Plant`.

Comment: @Nigenas `null instanceof Plant` will return `false`

Comment: Now it answers the question. The best solution would be to throw an exception though: `throw new IllegalStateException("Should never happen: nextInt(2) should never generate an int which is neither 1 nor 2");`. That way, if a developer changes to nextInt(3) and forgets to add a case in the switch, he'll get a clean, meaningful error message.

Comment: @Braj In my case `null` works perfectly as I have some safety checks before calling anything from Plant. JB Nizet's idea is probably the best.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet I have added your suggestion in my post also.

Comment: @Nigenas look at my edited post that is more better than switch case. In this case you don't need to put a `null` check on returned `Plant` object.

Answer (score 0):

No, from an object oriented perspective this is absolutely okay. A plant is a general entity, whereas the tree is specialized in some way.

The main point is that the tree is also a plant (is-a-relation) so a method returning a plant can return anything that is at least as general as a plant but also may be more specialized.